# Adding PhoneGap Build Android requirements

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

So I've upgraded my facebookConnectPlugin (cordova-plugin-facebook4/[npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4)) for iOS support, and my iOS build is now compiling - but now my Android is not.  The build error states:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'project'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         :project:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         :project:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1
```

This was described in their [issues list](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/154) of this repository (opened 22 days ago), with a [pull request](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/pull/171) that explained their fix (2 days ago).

I'm using the CLI version of 6.0.0.  Can anybody suggest anything else I can try.

Edit: I only upgraded to the cli 6.0.0 as I saw it was recently released and thought it may have the required dependencies - I'll try 5.4 and 5.2 later.

Edit: To your questions, Jesse;

1. Is this your first hybrid App? Yes
2. Are you using the Desktop App? No
3. What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Android 4.4+ (for websocket support), iOS 7+
4. Are you using CLI, SDK or Build ? Build - that is to confirm I do everything via `build.phonegap.com`.
5. Have you tried to communicate with the authors of the plugin? No, but that is definitely what I am doing next.

Comment: I'm on the [Adobe Communities for Phonegap Build](https://forums.adobe.com/community/phonegap/build) and
[Nitobi forum for Phonegap Build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi) all day, every day. I highly suggest you move back to cli-5.2.0 or cli-5.4.1. Unless you have a good reason to use cli-6.0.0. If you have such a reason, please put that in your Original Post.

Comment: Hey Jesse, rolled back to 5.4.1 and found that PGB doesn't support it, and went back to the 5.2.0 which I started with - same issue.

Comment: Okay. Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you using the Desktop App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Have you tried to communicate with the authors of the plugin? **please answer in the original post**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Phonegap Build too

Apparently the problem is with phonegap build and not with the plugin, as the mentioned Android Support Library is not yet updated.

A solution I found in the plugin [issues page](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/180) was to downgrade the plugin to use version 1.3.0:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" source="npm" version="1.3.0">
  <param name="APP_ID" value="APP_ID" />
  <param name="APP_NAME" value="APP_NAME" />
</gap:plugin>
```

Also exclude or comment out this as it creates another type of compilation error:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-support-v4" gap:platform="android" source="npm" spec="21.0.1" />
```

This worked for me and now my Android build works.

Temporary solution until Phonegap Build updates that library.

Comment: This sounds great! Yes it occurred to me that the issue is at least primarily with PGB to need an updated library, or at least supplied from maven.org.  I did try and use older versions, but did not go back this far - will apply this change later today and mark this as the answer if it works, a great temporary solution.

Comment: Fixed :)
It looks like I've made some syntax errors having modified the login script to suit this plugin, but should be on the straight and narrow now.

Comment: Glad this worked for you too! I actually tried version 1.7.0 again and it worked. So you should try it. :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem since yesterday. The solution for me was to update the Android Support Library via the SDK Manager (hint: run it as Admin, 'cause it wouldn't update anything for me otherwise.)

[image]

Comment: if this person is using *Phonegap Build*, a cloud-based service by Adobe/Phonegap, not only is your answer wrong, but misleading. Consider deleting it, if the person ever responds.

Comment: Well.. if this person *isn't* using Phonegap, which while not explicitly stated is implied by the fact that they're using the jeduan cordova-plugin-facebook4 (https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4), then the answer is entirely correct and to delete it would be a disservice to everyone else who comes across this issue. In fact, when I initially found this post, I tried your suggestion of downgrading to cli-5.2.0 and cli-5.4.1, neither of which resolved my issue. So maybe you should delete *your* comment?

Comment: We will wait and see. This could be another flake.

Comment: your answer is misleading. See answer accepted. This is the last I will say of this. Jesse

Comment: This should be the correct way to do, I agree with DaveDev. This is exactly what solved my problem.

@DaveDev, thank you!